# What is the correct way to prevent SQL injection on server side JS

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, code-injection, hana

I wanted to know the best practises around preventing SQL injection.

lets say from the client side (index.html) you have a form that submits to your serverside page an array of string values via $.ajax

```
var data_to_be_submitted = {
                          "searchTerms":descriptorArray,

                               };


             $.ajax({
                          url: 'get_fact_trans_volume.xsjs',
                           data:data_to_be_submitted,   
                      ....});
```

On the serverside (`get_fact_trans_volume.xsjs`) I do something like this:

```
var searchTerms = [];
searchTerms = $.request.parameters.get("searchTerms") ;

var quotedAndCommaSeparated = "'" + searchTerms.join("','") + "'";

var sqlQuery = "Select ... from table t where t.field in (%S)"

sqlQuery = sqlQuery.replace("%S", searchTerms .toString());
```

Is this following correct best practises? What are good ways to construct SQL queries using Javascript ?

Comment: What server side SQL library are you using?

Comment: If your library does not support prepared statements, find another one.

Comment: I'm not. I should've clarified, I don't have access to any SQL query builder library and I can't bring them in because of limitations. So I need to know how to do this using Vanilla JS.

Comment: Right, the correct answer is "use prepared statements".

Comment: @smooth_smoothie you must be using *something* to connect to the database.

Comment: He appears to be using something called OpenSAP XSJS. It's the first time I hear about it so I can hardly give any advice.

Comment: Okay it looks like they do have a PrepareStatement class. I had to dig around for the documentation. Thanks everyone

Comment: Combination of validating all variables and using query parameters.  JavaScript is probably a poor choice of programming languages for this.

Answer (score 1):

There is a PrepareStatement class.

http://help.sap.com/hana/SAP_HANA_XS_JavaScript_API_Reference_en/$.db.PreparedStatement.html